# oracle ora-00904 with symfony2 and doctrine2

Tags: sql, oracle, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a doctrine DQL that transforms into this SQL:

```
SELECT o0_.id AS ID0, 
o0_.pmn AS PMN1, 
o0_.neteo AS NETEO2, 
sum(o1_.monto_total) AS SCLR3, 
o1_.periodo AS PERIODO4, 
o1_.pagado AS PAGADO5 
FROM operador o0_ 
LEFT JOIN operador_hub o2_ ON o0_.id = o2_.operador_id 
LEFT JOIN outcollect o1_ ON o0_.id = o1_.operador_id 
WHERE o0_.ishub = 0 
AND o0_.neteo = 1 
AND o0_.incluirReportes = 1 
AND o0_.pmn NOT IN ('CHLTM', 'CHLCM') 
AND o0_.id NOT IN (SELECT o3_.id FROM operador o3_ LEFT JOIN operador_hub o4_ ON o3_.id = o4_.operador_id LEFT JOIN outcollect o5_ ON o3_.id = o5_.operador_id WHERE (o4_.desde <= o5_.periodo AND (o4_.hasta >= o5_.periodo OR o4_.hasta IS NULL))) 
AND o0_.activo = 1 
GROUP BY o0_.pmn, PERIODO4 
ORDER BY o0_.pmn ASC
```

this gives an `ORA-00904: "PERIODO4": identificador no válido`

the error is directly related to the GROUP BY o0_.pmn, PERIODO4 line

It seems related to doctrine that cannot translate the query to an ORACLE syntax. I'm using OCI8 driver.

Any thoughts?

---- edit ----

here is the DQL:

```
SELECT partial operador.{id, pmn, neteo},                           
sum(outcollect.montoTotal) as montoOut,
outcollect.periodo as periodo,
outcollect.pagado as pagado
FROM RoamingOperadoresBundle:Operador operador
LEFT JOIN operador.operadorHub operadorHub 
LEFT JOIN operador.outcollect outcollect
WHERE operador.ishub = 0
AND operador.neteo = 1                          
AND operador.incluirReportes = 1
AND operador.pmn not in('CHLTM', 'CHLCM')
AND operador.id not in(SELECT op.id 
FROM RoamingOperadoresBundle:Operador op
LEFT JOIN op.operadorHub opHub
LEFT JOIN op.outcollect out
WHERE (opHub.desde <= out.periodo and (opHub.hasta >= out.periodo or opHub.hasta is null)))
AND operador.activo = 1
GROUP BY operador.pmn, periodo ORDER BY operador.pmn
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you are generating this table expression, but you are getting the error because you aren't including all non-aggregated columns in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Also note - you can't group by an alias. You must refer to the column by specifying it in `table.column` form.

It should look like this:

`GROUP BY o0_.pmn, o0_.neteo, o1_.periodo, o1_.pagado`

Comment: thanks buddy!, now the error is this one:

SELECT o0_.id AS ID0,
       *
ERROR en linea 1:
ORA-00979: no es una expresion GROUP BY

so we are moving on. I will post the DQL

Comment: I am not familiar with doctrine2, so I don't know if you intended to generate the table expression in the style of your edit. However, standard SQL table expressions follow a `SELECT - FROM - WHERE - GROUP BY - HAVING - ORDER BY` logical pattern, and your SQL violates this by including 2 `FROM` and 2 `WHERE` clauses in the same table expression. This is probably why you are getting an error.